# WP_Query search within the page not working

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type called `book`. This book has multiple taxonomies such as `Book Category`, `Publishing Year`, `Print Status`.

All books listed on the page are called `books` and users are able to browse through the taxonomy terms. Like below
[image]

I want to show search results on the same page. Therefore I wrote a WP_Query with taxonomies, but I am not getting the results. Here is my code so far.

```
<?
$book = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'book',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'tax_query'=> array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'book_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $book_category,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'publishing_year',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $publishing_year,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'print_status',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $print_status,
        ),
    ),
));
if($book->have_posts()):
    while($book->have_posts()): $book->the_post();
    ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

My form setup as below:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/books/')); ?>">
```

These are the form fields:

```
<select name="book-category" class="form-select" id="book-category">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Book Category</option>
    <option value="category-01">Category 01</option>
    <option value="category-02">Category 02</option>
    <option value="category-03">Category 03</option>
</select>
<select name="publishing-year" class="form-select" id="publishing-year">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Publishing Year</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
<select name="print-status" class="form-select" id="print-status">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Print Status</option>
    <option value="in-print">In Print</option>
    <option value="not-in-print">Not in Print</option>
</select>
```

This is how I am assigning each submission into variables.

```
$book_category = $_GET['book-category'];
$publishing_year = $_GET['publishing-year'];
$print_status = $_GET['print-status'];
```

Also, I am getting the form submission data correctly.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I am getting the form submission data correctly."*, Can you show an example of the submission data and how you assign it to each variable?

Comment: @dvlpr.963 I have updated the question. The only thing I can't manage at the moment is if either taxonomy does not have a value, WP_Query is not working. I need to ignore the taxonomies which don't have a selected taxonomy term.